output of a command framed by a couple of '#' characters
I want to be greeted by
# #####################################################
# ### PostgreSQL 16.3 #################################
# #####################################################

on login to a postgres server.
so I add
echo "# #####################################################"
psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'}
echo "# #####################################################"

to the ~/.bashrc.
I now probably need some sort of echo with $(psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'}) but can not figure out how to add the leading/trailing # to it.
Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

Strongly related: bash script , echo output in box

I arrived here with cowsay in mind...

You should be able to output the result of that command using a combination of $() and quote marks like so-
echo "### $(psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'}) #############"

This should output the hashes but still evaluate and print the $() part as a command.

Note that the number of hashes to the right, after the output of the command in the substitution, probably has to be dynamically altered depending on the width of the command's output.

thx ... and weird, this is so obvious that I can't even begin to tell how I did not come up with this myself.

If you want to make the lines the same length, the tricky part is printing a correct amount of # signs dynamically. You could do something like this (in Bash or zsh):
#!/bin/bash
fill() {
    local width="$1" char="$2"
    printf -v str "%${width}s" ""
    printf "%s" "${str// /$char}"
}
fill 20 "#"  # prints 20 # signs

That abuses the printf format specifiers to print an empty string in a field of a given width, producing that many spaces. (i.e. %20s fills to 20 characters.) The spaces are then replaced with the character we actually want.
Then the whole box could be printed with something like this:
width=50
verstr=$(psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'})

printf "# %s\n" "$(fill $width "#")"
printf "# ### %s %s\n" "$verstr" "$(fill $(( width - ${#verstr} - 5)) "#")"
printf "# %s\n" "$(fill $width "#")"

where width is the number of # signs (after the initial one), and $(( width - ${#verstr} - 5)) simply counts how many are left to print after the version string, the first ### and the spaces on either side. If that gives a negative result, you'll get odd effects, though. :)
With
width=50
verstr="PostgreSQL 16.3"

the output is
# ##################################################
# ### PostgreSQL 16.3 ##############################
# ##################################################

(printf -v var and the ${var/pattern/replacement} aren't standard shell features. The first can be replaced with a command substitution, but the second may require forking off to tr.)

Of course, if you don't want to be that fancy, it's far simpler e.g. this:
verstr=$(psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'})
printf "# #####################################################\n"
printf "# ### %s\n" "$verstr"
printf "# #####################################################\n"

would print something like
# #####################################################
# ### PostgreSQL 16.3
# #####################################################

and would work in any POSIX-like shell.

Or, as mentioned in comments, you could print the full line of hash signs first, then a carriage-return to return back to the start, and then write over the line with no need to count characters.  On a terminal, the result is identical to printing just the required number of characters, but of course if you view the output with e.g. less or many other programs, the difference will be visible.
verstr=$(psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'})
printf "# #####################################################\n"
printf "# #####################################################\r" # \r not \n
printf "# ### %s \n" "$verstr"
printf "# #####################################################\n"

that would look like:
# #####################################################
# ### PostgreSQL 16.3 #################################
# #####################################################


Since we're already using awk it can do the fill (in any shell): pg_sel_version  | awk '{ f=sprintf("%50s",""); gsub(/ /,"#",f); l="# "; NF=2; print l f RS l $0 FS substr(f,2+length) RS l f }'

@dave_thompson_085, well, that's certainly also true! Though awk doesn't have Perl's x operator so I guess it's still either a loop or the printf trick... Anyway, I also wondered if we could dispense with awk and have psql itself print only the desired fields.

You could also use a tool for ASCII-art, e.g. install boxes. For details see also the long answer in related question.
Adapted the example:
psql -qAtc "SELECT version()" | awk {'print $1, $2'} | boxes -d shell -p a1

Should print like:
###################
#                 #
# PostgreSQL 16.3 #
#                 #
###################

See also:

Boxes - Draws ASCII Art Boxes and Shapes in Linux Terminal
10 Tools to Have Fun With ASCII Art in Linux Terminal


Simplified (version only)
Since psql already indicates the DBMS name "PostgreSQL", the server-version may suffice in print-out.
Consulting StackOverflow, linux - Which version of PostgreSQL am I running?, SHOW server_version; only returns the version-number, which makes parsing with awk obsolete.
This simplifies the one-liner to
psql -qAtc "SHOW server_version;" | boxes -d shell -p a1

Should print:
########
#      #
# 16.3 #
#      #
########


I was about to suggest an answer that effectively reimplemented boxes. Thank you for the pointer

Some things aren't actually worth writing code for, and this is one of those cases.
I would expect the version of PostGreSQL to change infrequently, so it shouldn't need to be calculated every time you log in.
There's already a mechanism to show the contents of a static file to everyone who logs in, without needing to change .bashrc at all: just write your desired message into /etc/issue.net (and /etc/issue) and let sshd (and the other login methods) take care of showing it to the user.
If you only want the message shown to yourself and not other users, add cat ~/.issue to .bash_profile or .profile (whichever exists) rather than .bashrc (which runs in every interactive shell, not just when you log in).
Then you just need to arrange for /etc/issue* or ~/.issue to be updated whenever the version of postgres changes; personally I would just edit it manually, but ...
If you really want it automated, consider adding an update-alternatives hook, or run a weekly cron job. (In the latter case you'll want to have a separate script that does the update; trying to cram the whole command into a crontab line needs extra \ that are hard to get right.
#!/bin/bash
# If the line above does not work on your system then change it to the actual path to your installed Bash; do NOT use "env". Once it works please delete this line.

IFS= read -r text < <(
  psql -qAtc 'select version();' 
)
text="###  $text  ###"
blank="###  ${text//?/ }  ###"
line=${text//?/#}
msg="\
$Line
$blank
$text
$blank
$line"

printf > "$HOME"/.issue '%s\n' "$msg"
printf > /etc/issue '%s\n' "$msg"




there's certainly a point to this, too. Though if one wants it to be up to date, it better be automated, because otherwise someone will forget about it... And a script to automatically fetch the version has the advantage that it can be copied to multiple hosts without changes, regardless of if they have a different version.
